# RegEx Match split by space escaping double quotes / single quotes?

Tags: regex

I have the following regex:

```
/(?:[^\s"]+|"[^"]*")+/g
```

this works great for double quotes

How can I make it also match paired single quotes?

```
`a string 'keep together' or "keep together"`
```

becomes

```
`a`, `string` `'keep together'`, `or` `"keep together"`
```

Comment: Following your pattern logic, use `/(?:[^\s"']+|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')+/g`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew seems to do the trick thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
/(?:[^\s"']+|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')+/g
         ^          ^^^^^^^^
```

The `'[^']*'` part will match a `'`, then any 0 or more occurrences of chars other than `'`, and then a `'`. A single quote must be added to the first negated character class, too.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/597l4Y/1)